# See Through Shader Approach

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am developing a surveying application on a 3d model, finished developing the measuring module but I am having a problem that the scntext added on the scnode root cannot see through the 3d model. I am using the SCNBillboardConstraint contraint to towards the current camera.

So is there a way for the scntext to see through or overwrite the model like this?
[So is there a way for the scntext to see through or overwrite the model like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4e5F.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to help you with a question like this. We need to see the code. But I try to give you some help anyway. The first thing is to print a enumerateChildNodes of rootNode to see what happens in the scene, like this:

```
  sceneView.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes {
    nodo,i in
    
    print(nodo.position) //position in all axis in relative way
    print(nodo.worldPosition) //position in all axis in absolute way

    //and so on

}
```

Use node.name property if you want to filter a particular node in the scene. Probably your text node is too little or have a misplaced position (under floor plane for example).

Comment: I aggree with Massimo - you could provide some code details. And please add a ScreenShot of your current situation, so we can see what's going on.